# Create new tablerow for every 8 entrys Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have documents that are uploaded to my site, and these are stored in a database. I want to make it so that every 8 documents uploaded, a new row in a table is created so that when a new document is uploaded, if there are already 8 documents in the table row, that document will be placed in a new row.

Currently I have it so that every time a document is added, a new table cell is created with the new document and its title inside. I just don't know how to make it so that after 8 documents instead of creating one very long table, a new table row is created to accomodate the new documents.

Below is my code and ruby loop for the table:

```
  <table>
  <% @documents.each_slice(8) do |document| %>
    <tr>
      <% document.each do |document| %>
      <td><%= document.title %>: <%= link_to "Download", Document.last.pdf.url(:original, false) %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And below is the outcome:

[image]

As you can see, I have created more than 8 documents, but they are not creating a new table row. Open to suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost right, except the facts that you have used the same `document` block argument in two different `do` blocks like here:

```
<table>
<% @documents.each_slice(8) do |document| %>
<tr>
  <% document.each do |document| %>
```

as well as the `end` statements have been used in a messy way.

---

Use this code snippet: Hope it works!

```
<table>
<% @documents.each_slice(8) do |eight_documents| %>
  <tr>
  <% eight_documents.each do |document| %>
    <td><%= document.title %>: <%= link_to "Download", Document.last.pdf.url(:original, false) %></td>
  <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: That works perfectly as I asked. Would is also be possible to create 8 cells in one column, and then create a new column after 8 have been created?

Comment: glad that it worked! in the latter case, you need to use twitter bootstrap grid to customize your table columns further. but that's another topic :)